# SF - Create Flow based on 'If Quote Line Items Name Contains'

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, quote, quotelineitem

***I am trying to create a flow based on the following:***

- When a Quote status changes to 'Accepted'
- Check all Quote Line Item Product Names
- If any Quote Line Item Product Names contain a certain string
- Send a Slack Message to Tech Support

***I need help setting up the Flow to make this happen. Here's what I have so far:***. This is sending a Slack message every time the Quote status is changed to 'Accepted' and not only when the realted Quote Line Item meets the criteria in the 'Decision' item shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by adjusting the 'Get Records' object.  Previously, I was just getting Quote Line Items, but I was NOT getting QuoteLineItems from the specific Quote Object, therefore the flow was always returning 'true'.